# Plan cache size and reserved memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, memory, dmv, plan-cache

When running a query including the Actual Execution Plan, the root operator (`SELECT`) tells me that the *Cached Plan Size* is 32KB.

A query that joins `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` and `sys.dm_os_memory_objects`, looking at the plan in question, says that values for `pages_in_bytes` and `max_pages_in_bytes` are 32768 (32KB), which matches the cached plan size.

What I don't understand is what the value in `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans.size_in_bytes`, which is 49152 (48KB) stands for. I've read BOL on all these columns, and especially `size_in_bytes` which says:

> "*Number of bytes consumed by the cache object.*"

I can't get that last bit of the puzzle in place, to understand what it really means.

I know that all operators (not talking about the additional memory grant used for sorts and hashes) requires some amount of fixed memory, to store state, make calculations etc., which is stored with the optimized plan in the cache, but where?

So, my questions are:

- What does `size_in_bytes` really mean
- Why is it a higher value than "Cached plan size"?
- Where is the fixed amount of memory for all operators/iterators reserved, is it with the "Cached plan size" (32Kb in my example), or anywhere else?

I know they're different DMVs with different functions, but they are related. The compiled (cached) plans in `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` joins `sys.dm_os_memory_objects` on `memory_object_address` column. The reason I post the questions here, is that I'm asking for help on this, understanding how to interpret the DMVs and their columns.

If `size_in_bytes` is the cached plan size, why does SQL Server say another value in actual execution plan?

New query, new numbers:

- Actual plan

  - Cached Plan Size 16KB
  - CompileMemory 96KB
- DMVs:

  - `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans.size_in_bytes` 24KB
  - `sys.dm_os_memory_objects.pages_in_bytes, .max_pages_in_bytes` 16KB.

Also, note that this query doesn't require any additional memory grants for sorts and hash operations.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5343.0 (X64)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason that the `size_in_bytes` field of the `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` DMV, at least in terms of "Compiled Plans", is larger than the `CachedPlanSize` attribute of the `QueryPlan` node in the XML plan is because a Compiled Plan is not the same thing as a Query Plan. A Compiled Plan is comprised of multiple Memory Objects, the combined size of which equates to the `size_in_bytes` field. So, the description of "*Number of bytes consumed by the cache object*" that you found in the documentation is accurate; it's just that it is easy to misinterpret what is meant by "cache object" given the name of the DMV and that the term "plan" has multiple meanings.

A Compiled Plan is a container that holds various pieces of information related to the query *batch* (i.e. not just a single statement), one (or more) of those pieces being the query plan(s). Compiled Plans have a top-level Memory Object of **MEMOBJ_COMPILE_ADHOC** which is the row in `sys.dm_os_memory_objects` that is linked via the `memory_object_address` field in both DMVs. This Memory Object contains the symbol table, parameter collection, links to related objects, accessor cache, TDS metadata cache, and possibly some other items. Compiled Plans are shared amongst Sessions/Users that are executing the same *batch* with the same Session settings. However, some related objects are *not* shared between Sessions/Users.

Compiled Plans also have one or more dependent objects that can be found by passing the `plan_handle` (in `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`) into the `sys.dm_exec_cached_plan_dependent_objects` DMF. There are two types of dependent objects: Executable Plan (Memory Object = **MEMOBJ_EXECUTE**) and Cursor (Memory Object = **MEMOBJ_CURSOREXEC**). There will be 0 or more Cursor objects, one per each cursor. There will also be one or more Executable Plan objects, one per each User executing that same *batch*, hence Executable Plans are *not* shared between Users. Executable Plans contain run-time parameter and local variable info, run-time state such as the currently executing statement, object ids for objects created at run-time (I assume this refers to Table Variables, Temporary Tables, Temporary Stored Procedures, etc), and possibly other items.

Each statement *within a multi-statement batch* is contained within a Compiled Statement (Memory Object = **MEMOBJ_STATEMENT**). The size of each Compiled Statement (i.e. `pages_in_bytes`) divided by 1024 should match the `CachedPlanSize="xx"` values of the `<QueryPlan>` nodes in the XML plan. Compiled Statements will often have one (possibly more?) associated runtime Query Plans (Memory Object = **MEMOBJ_XSTMT**). Finally, for each runtime Query Plan that is a query, there should be an associated Query Execution Context (Memory Object = **MEMOBJ_QUERYEXECCNTXTFORSE**).

With respect to Compiled Statements, single-statement batches do not have separate Compiled Statement (i.e. **MEMOBJ_STATEMENT**) or separate runtime Query Plan (i.e. **MEMOBJ_XSTMT**) objects. The value for each of those objects will be stored in the main Compiled Plan object (i.e. **MEMOBJ_COMPILE_ADHOC**), and in that case, the `pages_in_bytes` value for that main object divided by 1024 should match the `CachedPlanSize` size in the `<QueryPlan>` node of the XML plan. Those values will not equate, however, in multi-statement batches.

---

The `size_in_bytes` value can be derived by summing the entries in the `sys.dm_os_memory_objects` DMV (the items noted above in bold), all related by `dm_os_memory_objects.page_allocator_address` for that Compiled Plan. The trick to getting the correct value is to first get the `memory_object_address` from `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` for a particular Compiled Plan, then use that to get the corresponding **MEMOBJ_COMPILE_ADHOC** row from `sys.dm_os_memory_objects` based on its `memory_object_address` field. Then, grab the `page_allocator_address` value from `sys.dm_os_memory_objects` for that row, and use it to grab all rows from `sys.dm_os_memory_objects` that have the same `page_allocator_address` value. (Please note that this technique does not work for the other Cached Object types: **Parse Tree**, **Extended Proc**, **CLR Compiled Proc**, and **CLR Compiled Func**.)

Using the `memory_object_address` value obtained from `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`, you can see all of the components of the Compiled Plan via the following query:

```
DECLARE @CompiledPlanAddress VARBINARY(8) = 0x00000001DC4A4060;

SELECT obj.memory_object_address, obj.pages_in_bytes, obj.type
FROM   sys.dm_os_memory_objects obj
WHERE  obj.page_allocator_address = (
                               SELECT planobj.page_allocator_address
                               FROM   sys.dm_os_memory_objects planobj
                               WHERE  planobj.memory_object_address = @CompiledPlanAddress
                              )
ORDER BY obj.[type], obj.pages_in_bytes;
```

The query below lists all of the Compiled Plans in `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` along with the Query Plan and statements for each batch. The query directly above is incorporated into the query below via XML as the `MemoryObjects` field:

```
SELECT cplan.bucketid,
       cplan.pool_id,
       cplan.refcounts,
       cplan.usecounts,
       cplan.size_in_bytes,
       cplan.memory_object_address,
       cplan.cacheobjtype,
       cplan.objtype,
       cplan.plan_handle,
       '---' AS [---],
       qrypln.[query_plan],
       sqltxt.[text],
       '---' AS [---],
       planobj.pages_in_bytes,
       planobj.pages_in_bytes / 1024 AS [BaseSingleStatementPlanKB],
       '===' AS [===],
       cplan.size_in_bytes AS [TotalPlanBytes],
       bytes.AllocatedBytes,
       (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), obj.memory_object_address, 1)
               AS [memory_object_address], obj.pages_in_bytes, obj.[type]
               --,obj.page_size_in_bytes
        FROM   sys.dm_os_memory_objects obj
        WHERE  obj.page_allocator_address = planobj.page_allocator_address
        FOR XML RAW(N'object'), ROOT(N'memory_objects'), TYPE) AS [MemoryObjects]
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cplan
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cplan.[plan_handle]) sqltxt
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cplan.[plan_handle]) qrypln
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_memory_objects planobj
        ON planobj.memory_object_address = cplan.memory_object_address
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(domo.[pages_in_bytes]) AS [AllocatedBytes]
             FROM   sys.dm_os_memory_objects domo
             WHERE  domo.page_allocator_address = planobj.page_allocator_address) bytes
WHERE  cplan.parent_plan_handle IS NULL
AND    cplan.cacheobjtype IN (N'Compiled Plan', N'Compiled Plan Stub')
--AND cplan.plan_handle = 0x06000D0031CD572910529CE001000000xxxxxxxx
ORDER BY cplan.objtype, cplan.plan_handle;
```

Please note that:

- the `TotalPlanBytes` field is just a re-statement of the `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans.size_in_bytes` field,
- the `AllocatedBytes` field is the SUM of the related memory objects that typically matches `TotalPlanBytes` (i.e. `size_in_bytes`)
- the `AllocatedBytes` field will occasionally be greater than `TotalPlanBytes` (i.e. `size_in_bytes`) due to the memory consumption increasing during execution. This seems to happen mostly due to recompilation (which should be evident with the `usecounts` field showing `1`)
- the `BaseSingleStatementPlanKB` field *should* match the `CachedPlanSize` attribute of the `QueryPlan` node in the XML, but *only* when using a single query batch.
- for batches with multiple queries, there should be rows marked as `MEMOBJ_STATEMENT` in `sys.dm_os_memory_objects`, one for each query. The `pages_in_bytes` field for these rows should match the individual `<QueryPlan>` nodes of the XML plan.

Resources:

- [What are the different cached objects in the plan cache?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/05/04/what-are-the-different-cached-objects-in-the-plan-cache/)
- [1.0 Structure of the Plan Cache and Types of Cached Objects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2007/01/09/1-0-structure-of-the-plan-cache-and-types-of-cached-objects/)
- [2.0 Sql_Handle and Plan_Handle Explained](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2007/01/09/2-0-sql_handle-and-plan_handle-explained/)
- Documentation for [sys.dm_exec_cached_plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-cached-plans-transact-sql)
- Documentation for [sys.dm_os_memory_objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-memory-objects-transact-sql)
- Documentation for [sys.dm_exec_sql_text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql)
- Documentation for [sys.dm_exec_query_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-plan-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

**Pro SQL Server Internals has examined this issue.**

```
dbcc freeproccache
GO
DECLARE
@SQL nvarchar (MAX)
,@I INT = 0
while @I < 1000
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = N'declare @C int;select @C=ID from dbo.Employees where ID='
           + CONVERT (nvarchar (10), @I);

    EXEC (@SQL);
    SELECT @I += 1;
END
GO


SELECT
p.usecounts, p.cacheobjtype, p.objtype, p.size_in_bytes, t.[text]
FROM
sys.dm_exec_cached_plans p CROSS apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text (p.plan_handle) t
WHERE
p.cacheobjtype LIKE 'Compiled Plan%' AND
t.[text] LIKE '%Employees%'
ORDER BY
p.objtype DESC;
```

> there are 1,000 plans cached, each of which uses 32 KB of memory, **or 32
>   MB total. As you can guess**, ad-hoc queries in busy systems can lead to excessive plan cache memory usage.

```
exec sys.sp_configure N'optimize for ad hoc workloads', N'1';
reconfigure with override;
```

> **with the Optimize for ad-hoc workloads setting enabled, you would see the plan cache content. As you can see, it now uses just 272 KB of memory rather than the 32 MB it used to before**

[image]

[image]